# Illegal character in array arg. \begin{tabular}{l | S | r}

Tags: tables

I was reading table tutorial given here https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tables/
and in the section adding rows and columns they have a code which I was trying.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{
%round-mode = places,
%round-precision = 2, 
%}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\caption{Your first label}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{l | S | r}
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\hline
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

as mentioned in the tutorial I should get a table which is shown as Table 3 in the tutorial.
But when I compile the program in MikTex  I get error in lines

```
\begin{tabular}{l | S | r}
```

which is

```
Illegal character in array arg. \begin{tabular}{l | S | r}
```

so I wanted to know what is the error? Why it does not work as shown in the tutorial.

As mentioned in comments I added line `\usepackage{siunitx}`
When I add `\usepackage{siunitx}` I get message `Unfortunatley the package siunitx could not be installed` and an error `File siunitx.sty' not found. \begin`
 I am on a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: `S` is not one of the approved column types in the basic `tabular` environment.

Comment: Column `S` requires the package `siunitx`, uncomment the line `\usepackage{siunitx}` and then try...

Comment: When I add \usepackage{siunitx} I get message `Unfortunatley the package siunitx could not be installed `and an error `File siunitx.sty not found. \begin` I am on a Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: @koeradoera Please check your installation, hence `siunitx` package is default one with all types of `LaTeX` distribution...Else update your `package` manager