# very long time taken to compile pdf from tex studio

Tags: tables, pdftex, texstudio

I am using Tex Studio on Windows 10.
Here is the simple code which I am executing

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{
%round-mode = places,
%round-precision = 2, 
%}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}

\begin{tabularx}{| X | X | X |}
\hline
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\hline
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\caption{Your first label}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table} [h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|r | l |}
    \hline
    7C0 & hexadecimal \\
    3700 & octal \\
    \cline{2-2}} 11111000000 & binary \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Your second label}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}


\begin{tabular}{cc}
    boring cell content & \parbox[t]{5cm}{rather long par\\new par}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I clicked the arrow
[image: out put generation]
the arrow which is double generates the preview.I have previously written paper  in latex and used Tex studio. The same laptop and same setup. So I know it does not take this long time for simple code to compile and generate a preview pdf.
What I am doing is very simple I am not clear with usage of tabular in latex so I am trying to practise with it by example codes given https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabularx_package and https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tables/
so my programs are very simple sinppets of code which I am trying to practise. The code posted in above should not at all take a very very long time to compile. So what is the problem I am not able to understand. Here is a preview of settings if this helps
[image: settings page]

as suggested in comments I looked at the error messages here are the error messages

```
Environment tabularx undefined. \begin{tabularx}
Misplaced \noalign. \hline
Misplaced alignment tab character &. \textbf{Value 1} &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $\alpha$ &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. $\alpha$ & $\beta$ &
Misplaced \noalign. \hline
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 1 &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 1 & 1110.1 &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 2 &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 2 & 10.1 &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 3 &
Misplaced alignment tab character &. 3 & 23.113231 &
Misplaced \noalign. \hline
\begin{center} on input line 10 ended by \end{tabularx}. \end{tabularx}
Misplaced alignment tab character &. \cline{2-2}} 11111000000 &
```

as mentioned in comments I removed extra bracket in cline and included package tabularx

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{
%round-mode = places,
%round-precision = 2, 
%}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}

\begin{tabularx}{| X | X | X |}
\hline
\textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
$\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
\hline
1 & 1110.1 & a \\
2 & 10.1  & b \\
3 & 23.113231 & c \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\caption{Your first label}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}
Second table
\begin{table} [h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|r | l |}
    \hline
    7C0 & hexadecimal \\
    3700 & octal \\
    \cline{2-2} 11111000000 & binary \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Your second label}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}


\begin{tabular}{cc}
    boring cell content & \parbox[t]{5cm}{rather long par\\new par}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

now the errors I have are

```
line 12: Environment tabularx undefined. \begin{tabularx}
line 13: Misplaced \noalign. \hline
line 14: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \textbf{Value 1} &
line 14: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} &
line 15: Misplaced alignment tab character &. $\alpha$ &
line 15: Misplaced alignment tab character &. $\alpha$ & $\beta$ &
line 16: Misplaced \noalign. \hline
line 17: Misplaced alignment tab character &. 1 &
line 17: Misplaced alignment tab character &. 1 & 1110.1 &
line 18: Misplaced alignment tab character &. 2 &
line 18: Misplaced alignment tab character &. 2 & 10.1 &
line 19: Misplaced alignment tab character &. 3 &
line 19: Misplaced alignment tab character &. 3 & 23.113231 &
line 20: Misplaced \noalign. \hline
line 21: \begin{center} on input line 10 ended by \end{tabularx}. \end{tabularx}
line 33: Misplaced alignment tab character &. \cline{2-2}} 11111000000 &
```

the tex studio shows following in red
[image: table errors]
and following
[image: cline errors]

Comment: Your code is faulty. It does not compile at all.

Comment: ohh what is the mistake please tell.

Comment: Your editor should show your errors at the bottom. You can also look in the log-file, it should show errors too.

Comment: For starters: You need to follow the examples more closely and load the package `tabularx`, etc.

Comment: also an extra bracket in cline

Comment: ok I removed extra cline and included package tabularx so new code and new errors I have updated in question now.

Comment: The second argument of tabularx should be the desired width of the table.

Comment: so I need three columns and I specified `{X X X}` is that wrong

Comment: `{XXX}` is not wrong but you have to tell `tabularx` how wide your table should be. The correct syntax is `\begin{tabularx}{>table width here<}{>column specifiers here<}`. An example could be `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXX}`. The example will result an a table with three equally wide columns and justified text in them.  columns. The table will be as wide as the textwidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red quadratic, buttom in Texstudio shows, that the compiling is running.
When you want to cancel the process, press the red quadratic buttom. Then the compiling buttom will be green.
If you use Miktex with installing "packages on the fly", then the compiling time get longer, when packages will be installed.

Comment: ok yes this is the thing packages are installed on the fly. How can this be changed .

Comment: In the Miktex Console ( under settigs) you can disable the "installing on the fly". But then you must install missing packages also in the Miktex Console manually.

Comment: is it possible to have all packages pre installed by some option whether I know the name or not

Comment: You can install all missing packages also in the Miktex Console (under packages). At first you can sort the packages in installed and uninstalled by pressing the field "installed on". Then you can mark all not installed packages by "Shift-End" and then press the blue plus buttom at the top of the window.

Comment: Ok I checked the console as you say https://i.imgur.com/ULmebyK.jpg[/ but there does not seem to be an option of seeing not installed packages.

Comment: I have marked the field where you can sort the packages. [link](https://filehorst.de/d/dGzocGFx). It is the same as in the windows explorer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107757/discussion-between-uli-and-koeradoera).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\sisetup{table-format=4.6,
round-mode = places,
round-precision = 2, 
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
            \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{| c | S | c |}
                \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
                $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
                1 & 1110.1 & a \\
                2 & 10.1  & b \\
                3 & 23.113231 & c \\
            \end{tabularx}
        \caption{Your first label}
        \label{tab:table1}
    \vspace*{1cm}   
            \begin{tabular}{|r | l |}   \hline
                7C0 & hexadecimal \\
                3700 & octal \\ \cline{2-2}
                11111000000 & binary \\     \hline
        \end{tabular} \\[1cm]

        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            boring cell content & \parbox[t]{5cm}{rather long par\\new par}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I copy pasted the whole code you mentioned here in my tex studio ide the option to compile is greyed out. Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/u3eDW8U and more over the package siunitx is not present in my installation. I am not clear what is wrong, I had yesterday posted a question about not being able to use siunitx https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542773/illegal-character-in-array-arg-begintabularl-s-r I am not able to understand how should I check the error regarding siunitx.How to fix this.